# how to pass NetworkImageView(volley library) content to another actvity?

Tags: android, textview, imageview

I've two NetworkImageView elements in ListView, one is visible NetworkImageView element and another invisible NetworkImageView element. And I've implemented a onlickListener to Listview elements which calls a new activity whenever i select the element in the ListView. when calling a new activity i'm passing these two NetworkImageView elements to new activity. but I can only see the visible NetworkImageView element in new activity and a blank space instead of another NetworkImageView element.

code of main_activity.java

```
ListView lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id)
        {
            try{
                ImageView image1=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.visible);
                ImageView image2=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.invisible);
                image1.buildDrawingCache();
                image2.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bmp1=image1.getDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bmp2=image2.getDrawingCache();
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, new_Activity.class);
                i.putExtra("picture1", bmp1);
                i.putExtra("picture2", bmp2);
                startActivity(i);
                }
            catch (Exception e)
{Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}}});
```

code of new_Activity.java

```
Intent i = getIntent();

    Bitmap bmp1=(Bitmap)i.getParcelableExtra("picture1");
    Bitmap bmp2=(Bitmap)i.getParcelableExtra("picture2");

    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.desc_image1);
    ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.desc_image2);

    image1.setImageBitmap(bmp1);
    image2.setImageBitmap(bmp2);
```

XML files

activity_main.xml

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/visible"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/invisible"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

new_activity xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/desc_image1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/desc_image2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: can you post piece of code you are using to pass ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I meet a similar problem. In my ListView, each item contains an ImageView to display images from server, and I need to show it in a View to support scale feature when user click the ImageView.

I've tried this:

```
holder.iv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = ((ImageView) v).getDrawingCache();
mBrowseImageListener.onBrowseImage(bitmap);
```

But when the list length over a screen, I get a wrong bitmap, often the Bitmap current shown on another item.

And I tried this:

```
holder.iv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = ((ImageView) v).getDrawingCache();
mBrowseImageListener.onBrowseImage(bitmap);
holder.iv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Unfortunately, this caused an fatal exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap
```

**Finally I found this solution:**

```
Drawable drawable = holder.iv.getDrawable();
if (!(drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable)){
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "This drawable is not an instance of BitmapDrawable!");
    return;
}
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
if (bitmap==null || bitmap.isRecycled()){
    Log.w(LOG_TAG, "This bitmap was recycled!");
    return;
}
mBrowseImageListener.onBrowseImage(bitmap);
```

Hope this helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that image has been set in the invisible NetworkImageView.
Just make it visible and check if the image has been set.

like...

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/invisible"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Also,

```
bmp2=image2.getDrawingCache();
```

takes only the visible part, i guess.

Thanks.

Comment: yeah it is working for **android:visibility="visible"**, but its not working for **android:visibility="invisible"** and **android:visibility="gone"**

Comment: loader.thumbNail.getDrawable(); may be

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Bitmap bmp1=image1.getDrawingCache();
```

try

```
Bitmap bmp1 = ((BitmapDrawable)image1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```